# PHP HTML decode string-utf8

Tags: php, html, decode

I have tried string in database . I want to display it in webpage .
I tried

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Also

```
 utf8_decode($n1);
```

Also

```
html_entity_decode($n1, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

Nothing works I see the string as it is.
I have successfully didplayed this text in android device using URLdecoder method

The sample string is

```
 %E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%80+%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%81+%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA+%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%9F+%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%9F%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A1
```

It is in Hindi
I hope you can help me .Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you've provided is URL encoded. If you pass it to `urldecode()`, it'll render just fine:

```
urldecode("%E0E0[snip]%E0%A4%A1"); //  करणी माँ ग्रुप प्राइवेट लिमिटेड
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how you suspected.

Comment: You can recognize URL encoded strings by the %-characters. Charset encoding/decoding issues mostly cause characters being rendered as � (replacement character), or other 'weird' characters. By the way, please accept my answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to change the charset in the database 
http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php. 
you will need to change it in the code where you connect to the database in the link you can get various examples